# Trying to send email using command in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, email, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to send email using task scheduler in laravel 5.4 and below is code

I made a mail controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

# MAiler
use App\Mail\Mailtrap;
use App\Mail\EmailNotification;

class MailController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Send email
     * @return
     */
    public function index(){
      $user = Auth::user();
      Mail::to($user)->send(new EmailNotification());
    }

}
```

Next, I created a command and use the controller in there

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Http\Controllers\MailController;

class SendNotifications extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'SendNotifications:notification';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'This will send email';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $mail = new MailController();
        $mail->index();
    }
}
```

and in kernel

```
namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
      'App\Console\Commands\SendNotifications'
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('SendNotifications:notification')
                 ->everyMinute();
    }

    /**
     * Register the Closure based commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

when I try to send email in controller using route in web.php, it successfully send an email to mailtrap.io but, when i try to send it in the background using this command

`php artisan SendNotification:notification`

I got this error

`Trying to get property of non-object`

I don't know why it was supposed to be successful because it just called the email in the controller or I implemented this wrong

can you guide me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you work on different sessions. You probably logged in on browser and created session for this user however this session is not same in your command line.

So your problem occurs in this line `$user = Auth::user();`

If you `dd($user)` on your console command you will notice **$user** is empty

and thats why you are getting **try to get property of non object** error